# NodeJS app queries sometimes hang until cmd line is modified

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, cmd, sequelize.js

please excuse my newness to Node and hosting Node apps as I ask this little question about hosting my app.

I have an app living on another laptop opened for users to access via IP (this is a temp solution and not a part of my question).  Right now I remote access the computer and run a CMD line "nodemon server.js" to start the server.  The app is supported by MySQL db and connected with sequelize ORM.

My issue is that sometimes user's can't log in because the query is not going through.  I noticed that if I interact with the cmd line in any way (focus and press any key), any queries that were hung up will go through.

I dont know if this is due to

1. Running the server from cmd line (I like to do this because I could see queries real-time)
2. Interacting with the cmd line while the server is running (Could text area be disabled?  App packaged?)

Any insight on this would help.  Again sorry if this is a silly human error or basic mistake.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodemon is a development tool rather than running a production app - if this event loop blocks you might find it unresponsive as it's watching for changes on the filesystem (using a lot of memory).

You can try configure a better tool for monitoring and launching multiple node processes to serve your users. If one is busy then a new user should be sent to another node process running the same application. Also, if the process hits a limit or falls over it should start again automatically meaning you don't have to manually trigger this like with nodemon. I'd recommend [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io) for this in your case.

Comment: Just an update, this solution is working perfectly.  Thanks again.